# Failed installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new using ruby. I am installing ruby on subsystem Linux.I follow the instruction in https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-ruby-on-rails/. And get error in download the RVM installer script and install the RVM. I got message

```
 "mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/usr/share/rvm/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX’: Permission denied".
```

I change the command to

```
  curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby
```

then I get error in the following step. It says "-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory"

What can I do to fix this ?

Thank You :)

Comment: Follow the instructions on the [official site](https://rvm.io). I wouldn't trust "howtoforge" any more than I would "wikihow".

Answer (score 0):

check /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh if this file was not removed by implode

Also make sure there is no simple

```
 source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

in any of your shell initialization files?

```
grep -rn rvm ~/.bash*
```